# How do I prevent physics glitches in Trials Fusion?

Tags: trials-fusion

[image: 310H55V]

The ragdoll physics in Trials Fusion isn't so well-developed. I often encounter extreme glitches in user-created tracks. When the bike falls from a high place, the rider sometimes glitches through the ground and spasms randomly while making screaming noises. Objects have a "fast object" setting that prevents them from moving through other objects at the expense of performance, but the rider and the bike do not. How do I prevent physics glitches in Trials Fusion?

Comment: You might be able to find some mod/unofficial patch to help with the physics stimulation, but that's your best bet. Physics glitches are a part of any game with a physics engine. They're bound to happen. It's just that the ragdoll physics for this game isn't very well developed (I own the game and I know how crazy it is). I don't really think you can ask how to fix the physics glitches for a game, because it is simply a limitation of the game's engine.